# TypeError in Hardhat-Chai Matchers - isAddress not a function

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, chai

I'm encountering a TypeError in my Hardhat test script that involves the isAddress function from the @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers library. The error seems to be causing issues with my test suite. Below is the relevant code snippet: here my code.

```
const { expect, assert } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

const {
  addressFactory,
  addressRouter,
  addressFrom,
  addressTo,
} = require("../utils/AddressList");

const { erc20ABI, factoryABI, routerABI } = require("../utils/AbiList");

describe("read and write blockchain", () => {
  let provider,
    contractFactory,
    contractRouter,
    contractToken,
    decimals,
    amountIn,
    amountOut;

  provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
      ""
    );
    contractFactory = new ethers.Contract(addressFactory, factoryABI, provider);
    contractRouter = new ethers.Contract(addressRouter, routerABI, provider);
    contractToken = new ethers.Contract(addressFrom, erc20ABI, provider);
  });

  it("connects to the provider, factory, token, and router", () => {
    assert(provider._isProvider);

    expect(contractFactory.address).to.equal(
      "0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f"
    );
    expect(contractRouter.address).to.equal(
      "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"
    );
    expect(contractToken.address).to.equal(
      "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"
    );
  });
});
```

**Full error**

```
`read and write blockchain
    1) connects to the provider, factory, token, and router


  0 passing (96ms)
  1 failing

  1) read and write blockchain
       connects to the provider, factory, token, and router:
     TypeError: (0 , ethers_1.isAddress) is not a function
      at tryGetAddressSync (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/internal/addressable.ts:29:16)
      at Proxy.<anonymous> (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/internal/addressable.ts:53:20)
      at Proxy.overwritingMethodWrapper (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/overwriteMethod.js:78:33)
      at Proxy.<anonymous> (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/internal/bigNumber.ts:193:14)
      at Proxy.overwritingMethodWrapper (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/overwriteMethod.js:78:33)
      at doAsserterAsyncAndAddThen (node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:289:22)
      at Proxy.<anonymous> (node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:255:20)
      at Proxy.overwritingMethodWrapper (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/overwriteMethod.js:78:33)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/SendSwapTx.js:32:40)`
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide the full error traceback? (Also, you have an API key in your code, please scrub it, for your sake.)

Comment: I added full error

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your version of ethers.js is not compatible with the version of chai that you are using. I would assume that you are using ethers@5.7.2 in this project for JsonRpcProvider to work. I reinstalled hardhat@2.9.3 so that all depencies would be compatible. I'll attach a `package.json` that should work for you.

```
 {
  "name": "hardhattutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.5",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.6.5",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```